# How to generate client secret in azure app registration in Azure AD from CLI?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-cli

How can I use AZ commands to create client secret the same way I can do it from the portal?
[image: Creating client secret from portal]

Answer (score 29):

You are looking for [`az ad app credential reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-credential-reset), it appends or overwrites an application's password(i.e. `client secret`) or certificate credentials.

```
az ad app credential reset --id
                           [--append]
                           [--cert]
                           [--create-cert]
                           [--credential-description]
                           [--end-date]
                           [--keyvault]
                           [--password]
                           [--years]
```

Sample(you can also specify other parameters, it depends on you):

```
az ad app credential reset --id xxxxxxxxxxxx --append
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly does append do? Will it create a second secret?

Comment: @Nicolai yes it creates an additional client secret every time you run it with --append

Comment: I get "Property identifierUris is invalid." no matter if I use powershell (AzureAD) or the Cli :/

Comment: Just in case anyone is equally confused, there can be a lag between running this command, and the new secret being visible in the Azure Portal.

Also, you can use `--display-name` to set a Description.

Answer (score 0):

**Get ID Client of app register for example: "appId": "b23e2416-xxxx-xxxx-98d4"**

**Create:**

```
az ad app credential reset --id b23e2416-xxxx-xxxx-98d4 --append \
  --display-name 'Description: Secret Bolivian client' --end-date '2024-12-31'
```

**Output:**

```
The output includes credentials that you must protect. 
Be sure that you do not include these credentials in your code or check the credentials into your source control. 
For more information, see https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli
{
   "appId": "b23e2416-xxxx-xxxx-98d4",
   "password": "rp28Q~VNlFt-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "tenant": "67f3b853-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
}
```